# Saving TTS audio files to shared storage in android 10

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text-to-speech, android-10.0

I want to save my audio file to shared storage in android 10 which is created using :

```
textToSpeech.synthesizeToFile(text,params,file,"utterance_id");
```

***file*** is of ParcelFileDescriptor type which is created using createFile() method:

```
public void createFile()
    {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues(4);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, "Audioasas");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED, (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000));
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RELATIVE_PATH, "Music/Recordings/");

        audiouri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
        try {
            file=getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(audiouri,"w");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
   
 }
```

The problem here is that below method

```
public int synthesizeToFile (CharSequence text, 
                Bundle params, 
                ParcelFileDescriptor fileDescriptor, 
                String utteranceId)
```

is added in API level 30 (Android 11).

For android 10 we have:

```
public int synthesizeToFile (CharSequence text, 
                Bundle params, 
                File file, 
                String utteranceId)
```

But `getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(audiouri,"w")` method always return FileDescriptor object.

Therefore my question is how can I save my audio file to shared storage using

```
public int synthesizeToFile (CharSequence text, 
                Bundle params, 
                File file, 
                String utteranceId)
```

```
    or using any other method.
    Thanks
```

Comment: Just set up your File instance with right path . You dont need media store.

Answer (score 0):

Use fdopen()

`FILE* fp = fdopen(fd, "w");`